# What endianness has received packet in Java?

Tags: java, udp, endianness

I am working on a little UDP Java Server, which receives UDP Datagram Packets from a device that sends some kind of status messages.
All multibyte numbers (e.g. field LEN: 3 bytes) are sent in little-endian.

Since Java only works on big-endian, my question is the following:
Are these numbers automatically converted to big-endian upon receival?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What endianness has received packet in Java?

It has whatever the sender put in it.

> Are these numbers automatically converted to big-endian upon receival?

Java doesn't change anything.

Comment: I guess the next question is how to change them

Comment: @ScaryWombat So let him ask it then.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Maybe anything. I don't see the point in speculating. I've answered the question he asked. If you have an answer of your own I suggest you post it.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but your one-liner you posted at the time of review (I see you have edited it since) seemed more like a comment as no explanation or references were given. This was passed to the low-quality review queue, and I simply voted accordingly. The comment was auto-generated. If you do not wish for such comments on your answer in the future, I strongly suggest you improve on them (which you did, and that's a good thing). Still, it lacks official references and it still looks like a personal opinion/comment to me.